# how to set page size in crystal report for thermal printer in C# windows application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows, thermal-printer

I know width of thermal printer is 3 inch or 4 inches but i did not know how to set height of receipt in my crystal report. If i set it 6 to 10 inches and my product in invoice is more then 4 then my footer of receipt is gone ,please suggest me what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot set height. You have to design report, not containing anything in page footer section; your receipt footers are best to place into group footer (which should not have option "print at bottom of page"). While designing report, you need to have proper printer driver installed; usually you can set there paper type as "continous roll", what Crystal may see as 10foot/3meters or something.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal printer should cut off when it read a cut command . 
Try call cut command after print the report, no need to set height I believe.

Comment: Have you used Crystal Reports (in tandem with label/receipt printers)? It may advance paper for defined length of receipt (10 foot for example) before returning control to application. Depends on printer driver options however.